# Structs for file I/O

Tags: c, file, struct, io

I was trying to figure out the best way to keep a record of file pointers as well as individual information for each file such as a file path.

My question is, having a folder struct that holds an array of file pointers, and a file struct that holds information for files, how could merge these two concepts so that can I hold an array of file pointers, and store the file path for each of those files?

**Header file for a folder struct below:**

```c
#ifndef FOLDER_STRUCT_H
#define FOLDER_STRUCT_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct folder_
{
    FILE **files;
    size_t current_size;
    size_t capacity;
};

typedef struct folder_ folder_t;

folder_t *folder_create(size_t initial_size); //-----------------------Create a folder struct

void folder_destroy(folder_t *folder); //------------------------------Destroy a folder struct

bool folder_insert_file(folder_t *const folder, FILE *const file); //--Insert a file

FILE *folder_get_file(folder_t *const folder, size_t index); //--------Get a file by index

FILE **folder_get_file_list(folder_t *const folder); //----------------Get a list of files

int folder_get_size(folder_t *folder); //------------------------------Get folder size

int folder_get_total_capacity(folder_t *folder); //--------------------Get folder capacity

#endif
```

**Header file for a file struct used to record file information such as a file path:**

```c
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct file_
{
    FILE *file;
    char *file_path;
};

typedef struct file_ file_t;

#endif
```

Comment: Why don't you put a `struct file_ **` in the `struct folder_` instead of using `FILE **`?

Answer (score 0):

The generic approach is if you need both at the same time use another struct, and if you need either use a union probably with a tag field to tell which of the struct it holds.  In your case, it sounds like you have `1` folder to n files, so your `folder_file_` struct would have an array of `files_`.  If you have more than one folder, then you need an array of `folder_file_`.

`FILE *` usually implies an open file handle.  Is that really your use case?  Opposed to a bunch of paths, and you only open the file as you have to operate on it.  Also, why is `FILE **` opposed to a `FILE *`?

Answer (score 0):

Usually is best to let the system manage the file pointers. The file can be reopened outside your `struct` for example. Or just closed. The `struct` can get a copy of a `FILE*` but there is no way to know if it points to the same file as of the moment of creation.

Anyway, sometimes we may need a way to store info for a collection of files.

### An EXAMPLE

```
typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    FILE* F;

}   File;

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    size_t cap;   // capacity
    size_t inc;   // increment
    File** info;  // data array

}   Folder;
```

Inside `File` we can store sizes, dates, maybe permissions.

`Folder` is an array of pointers to `File`. `cap` and `size` are the usual, `inc` is the size of increment of `Folder` in files.

A few functions are implemented:

```
Folder* create(size_t capacity, size_t step);
Folder* destroy(Folder*);
int     insert(File*, Folder*);
int     show(Folder*, const char*);
int     trim(Folder*);

int     get_pos(const char* f_name, Folder*);
```

- `insert()` accepts a `File` pointer is easy to customize `File`.
- `trim()` releases all pointers not in use
- `show()` accepts a title, for convenience
- `get_pos()` returns the position of the provided file in the array
- `destroy()` returns `NULL` to ease in invalidate the pointer in the same line

#### `main` for this test

```
int main(void)
{
    const char tst_size = 10;
    const char* scan[] = {"File_7533.tst", "File_7500.tst"};
    srand(220520);

    Folder* tst = create(4, 4);
    show(tst, "just created");

    char f_name[20] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < tst_size; i += 1)
    {
        sprintf(f_name, "File_%04d.tst", 1+rand()%10000);
        insert_this(f_name,NULL,tst);
    }
    sprintf(f_name, "%d files inserted", tst_size);
    show(tst, f_name);
    trim(tst);
    show(tst, "after trim()");
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(scan) / sizeof(scan[0]);i+=1)
        printf( "search por \"%s\" returned %d\n", scan[i],
            get_pos(scan[i], tst));
    tst = destroy(tst);
    return 0;
}
```

- a Folder is created with size 4 and incrementable in groups of 4
- 10 files are inserted
- the contents are listed
- search for 2 files
- the thing is destroyed

#### test output

```
just created
[0/4 files (step = 4)]

insert() size extended to 8
insert() size extended to 12
10 files inserted
[10/12 files (step = 4)]
  0  File_2037.tst
  1  File_5785.tst
  2  File_6602.tst
  3  File_7231.tst
  4  File_0854.tst
  5  File_7102.tst
  6  File_7533.tst
  7  File_6460.tst
  8  File_1717.tst
  9  File_1948.tst

trim() new size: 10
after trim()
[10/10 files (step = 4)]
  0  File_2037.tst
  1  File_5785.tst
  2  File_6602.tst
  3  File_7231.tst
  4  File_0854.tst
  5  File_7102.tst
  6  File_7533.tst
  7  File_6460.tst
  8  File_1717.tst
  9  File_1948.tst

search for "File_7533.tst" returned 6
search for "File_7500.tst" returned -1
Folder structure destroyed
```

#### stuff.h

```
#ifndef STUFF_H
#define STUFF_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    FILE* F;

}   File;

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    size_t cap;   // capacity
    size_t inc;   // increment
    File** info;  // data array

}   Folder;

Folder* create(size_t capacity, size_t step);
Folder* destroy(Folder*);
int     insert(File*, Folder*);
int     show(Folder*, const char*);
int     trim(Folder*);

int     get_pos(const char* f_name, Folder*);

#endif
```

#### stuff.c

```
#include "stuff.h"

Folder* create(size_t capacity, size_t step)
{
    Folder* nw = (Folder*)malloc(sizeof(Folder));
    if (nw == NULL) return NULL;
    nw->size = 0;
    nw->cap  = capacity;
    nw->inc = step;
    nw->info = (File**) malloc(nw->cap*sizeof(File*));
    for (int i = 0; i < nw->cap; i += 1)
        nw->info[i] = NULL;
    return nw;
}

Folder* destroy(Folder* f)
{
    if (f == NULL) return NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < f->size; i += 1)
    {
        free(f->info[i]->name);
        free(f->info[i]);
    }
    free(f->info);
    free(f);
    printf("Folder structure destroyed\n");
    return NULL;
}

int insert(File* item, Folder* f)
{
    if (f == NULL) return -1;
    if (item == NULL) return -2;
    if (f->size >= f->cap)
    { // extends folder struct size
        size_t  new_size = f->cap + f->inc;
        File* p = realloc((void*)f->info, new_size*sizeof(File*));
        if (p == NULL) return -3; // error extending
        f->info = (File**) p;
        f->cap = new_size;
        printf("insert() size extended to %zd\n", f->cap);
    };
    // ok, new File then
    File* nw   = (File*)malloc(sizeof(File));
    nw->name = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(item->name));
    strcpy(nw->name, item->name);
    nw->F = item->F;
    f->info[f->size]      = nw;
    f->size += 1;
    return (int)f->size;        
}

int show(Folder* f, const char* msg)
{ 
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s\n", msg);
    printf(
        "[%zd/%zd files (step = %zd)\n", f->size, f->cap,
        f->inc);
    for (int i = 0; i < f->size; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%3d  %s\n", i, f->info[i]->name);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int trim(Folder* f)
{
    if (f == NULL) return -1;
    if (f->cap == f->size) return 0; // nothing to do
    File*  p = realloc((void*)f->info, f->size * sizeof(File*));
    if (p == NULL) return -3;  // error extending
    f->info = (File**) p;
    f->cap  = f->size;
    printf("trim() new size: %zd\n", f->cap);
    return 0;
};


int get_pos(const char* f_name, Folder* f)
{
    if (f_name == NULL) return -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < f->size; i += 1)
        if (strcmp(f_name, f->info[i]->name) == 0) return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Note to SO *"code reviewers"*: I do cast all `malloc()` pointers, as I do not like implicit things and I like them as additional reminders of things to come.